# Large database query: optimisation

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, activerecord

I have a `Product` model, with a `description` attribute.
When new products are created, I need to look for products having some a corresponding reference in their description and create a `Link` object between them.

Example:

```
Product 1
Description: ".... 58274072 ... "
```

I need to look for all the products having `58274072` in their description:

```
similar_products = Product.where("description like ?", "%58274072%")
```

I have two problems:

- this query can take several seconds to run given the large amount of products records we have. Is there a faster way to do the query ?
- I'm running this query in batch jobs, so there potentially are 10s of jobs running at the same time and trying to perform this query. When benchmarking one query alone, let's say it takes 2 seconds to run. When running it in a batch, it takes up to 6 seconds. Would this be caused by a number of database connections too low ?

How can I solve these problems ?

Comment: To me it looks like this is more of a database question rather than front-end. If I had such a query executed often, I would think supporting in the backend such as using a full text index, tsvector, reference keywords as array indexed etc depending on the database you are using.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I haven't tagged it as frontend

Comment: @GrahamSlick You tagged ruby-on-rails, but did not tag your SQL platform

Comment: @CraigYoung my bad, edited

Comment: Product.where("description like ?", "%58274072%") implicitly states that you are trying to solve that in frontend, no? There were no info on the database you are using and\or details on what exactly you want to search (probably not every word entered in the description).

Comment: Don't use wildcards in the `like` pattern.  These are forcing a full table scan, regardless of any indexes or partitions you have on the table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks for your input, what alternatives do I have ?

Comment: Ah, now tagged as postgresql. I would look into tsvector, tsquery then (can be indexed). Or having another field for array of 'search keywords" that could be indexed.

Comment: @CetinBasoz thanks I'll try that. Any idea for the second issue ? Is it due to too few connections ?

Comment: I don't know really, you are using RoR with activerecords which I don't use and there is only part of the code. Probably in "batch" you are querying one after another instead of doing the searches concurrently in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

To optimise index on LIKE you should use trigam extension.

For this you need to install the module pg_trgm which provides operator classes for GIN and GiST trigram indexes to support all LIKE and ILIKE patterns:

Example index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON product USING gin (description gin_trgm_ops);
```

or:

```
CREATE INDEX ON product USING gist (description gist_trgm_ops);
```

You need to choose between GIN or GiST ... GIN is faster for query, but slower to create, slower to update, and usually larger than GiST.

Try this if it solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `like`, I suggest to create table product_references with 2 columns: `product_id`, `reference` (this column can be indexed). One product can has multiple references so that it will has multiple product_references row. Then the flow should be changed as following:

- When a product is create, parse references in that product description and search similar products in product_references table
- Create `Link` object as your business rule
- Create new product_reference rows for newly product

The steps to parse, search, link and create new product_reference can be handled by background job.